# How to load a graphml file into a remote instance of Janusgraph, from a local gremlin-console

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

How to load a graphml file into a remote instance of Janusgraph, from a local gremlin-console

Eventually, I want to create JanusGraph on a remote VM but for this PoT, I've created a local docker image with

`docker run --rm --name janusgraph-default janusgraph/janusgraph:latest`

Which works fine. I then started gremlin-console with:

`docker run --rm --link janusgraph-default:janusgraph -e GREMLIN_REMOTE_HOSTS=janusgraph \ -it janusgraph/janusgraph:latest ./bin/gremlin.sh`

This also works fine. On the gremlin-console I ran

`:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml`

Then

`:> g.addV('person').property('name', 'chris')`

to test it had worked, I ran
`:> g.V().values('name')` which returned `chris`

Having (I think) proved that gremlin-console can control the gremlin-server in the docker image, I wanted to import K Lawrence's `air-routes-latest.graphml`, with a view to trying to create some CRUD operations in Node.js

All the docs I can find only deal with local import and not remote

I tried:

`:> graph.io(graphml()).readGraph("/home/me/Downloads/air-routes.graphml")`, which returned

`/home/me/Downloads/air-routes.graphml (No such file or directory)`

Stack Trace:

```
Display stack trace? [yN]y
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/greg/Downloads/air-routes.graphml (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphml.GraphMLIo.readGraph(GraphMLIo.java:91)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.Io$readGraph.call(Unknown Source)
        at Script5.run(Script5.groovy:1)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:674)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:376)
        at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$0(GremlinExecutor.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm confident that's really where it is (on the same machine as the console) but it made me wonder whether the import has a context of the remote server (in this case the docker image, but potentially a remote VM) or the local console? I can't find any help to shine a light on this help, please?

```
 Gremlin.version()
==>3.4.4
```

gremlin-console janusgraph tinkerpop gremlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Stephen's response, I tried the following, which worked:

Setting up Janusgraph server to import air-routes.graphml

bash terminal 1  (su):

```
docker run --name janusgraph-default --volume /home/greg/Downloads/gremlin:/dataImports janusgraph/janusgraph:latest
```

(if necessary, remove a clashing container with `docker container stop <pid>` )

This mounts the native folder `/home/greg/Downloads/gremlin` as `/dataImports` in the image, so the [air-routes.graphml](https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-data/air-routes-latest.graphml) file can be imported (you'll need to download from this link and substitute your own native file path to the download)
It's a useful graphml data-set to play with. Read about it [here](http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#airrouteupdates) and [here](http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#airrouteupdates).

To run the import, open a new bash terminal 2 (su):

```
docker run --rm --link janusgraph-default:janusgraph -e GREMLIN_REMOTE_HOSTS=janusgraph -it janusgraph/janusgraph:latest ./bin/gremlin.sh
```

This links to the janusgraph server (no port binding required) and opens the gremlin-console.

On the console, run:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
```

Then import the graphml file with

```
:> graph.io(graphml()).readGraph("/dataImports/air-routes.graphml")
```

It should return null. Once it has, run queries like:

```
:> g.V().has('airport','code','DFW').values()
```

Answer (score 4):

At this time, Gremlin `io()` does not work in this fashion. When your `io()` step is evaluated it uses the local file system where it is executed to do its work. In your case, you have a docker container running on the same system, so you could technically do what you are asking I think but I would think that the Docker container would need to be configured to mount `/home/greg/Downloads/` in such a fashion that it would be available to it. Docker will be isolated to it's own file space otherwise. I think you need a Docker `volume` or `bind` [mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to get this working properly.